# How to write a try-get function like in C#?

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, scripting

I'm writing a PowerShell script that loads an assembly if it's not already loaded. My logic for this in C# would be the following:

```cs
void DoSomething(string assemblyFilePath)
{
    string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(assemblyFilePath);

    Assembly assemblyObject;
    if (!TryGetAssembly(name, out assemblyObject))
    {
        assemblyObject = LoadAssemblyFrom(assemblyFilePath);
    }

    // Do something with assemblyObject.
}
```

I'm trying to translate this into PowerShell, but it's not working out so far. Here is my progress:

```bsh
function TryGet-Assembly($assembly, [ref] $cached)
{
    $domain = [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain

    foreach ($reference in $domain.GetAssemblies())
    {
        # GetName() has a type of AssemblyName,
        # so we need to use GetName().Name to get a string
        $name = $reference.GetName().Name
        if ($name -eq $assembly)
        {
            $cached = $reference
            return $true
        }
    }

    return $false
}

function Get-Namespaces($assembly)
{
    # Load the assembly, or retrieve it if it's cached
    $name = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($assembly)
    if (-not TryGet-Assembly $name $assemblyObject)
    {
        $assemblyObject = Load-Assembly $assembly
    }

    # Do the actual work
    $types = $assemblyObject.GetTypes()
    return $types | ? IsPublic | select Namespace -Unique
}
```

For some reason, I seem to be getting a syntax error when PowerShell tries to run the script. Here is the output:

```
At C:\Users\James\Code\csharp\Shims.Xaml\generate.ps1:83 char:13
+     if (-not TryGet-Assembly $name $assemblyObject)
+             ~
Missing expression after unary operator '-not'.
At C:\Users\James\Code\csharp\Shims.Xaml\generate.ps1:83 char:14
+     if (-not TryGet-Assembly $name $assemblyObject)
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'TryGet-Assembly' in expression or statement.
At C:\Users\James\Code\csharp\Shims.Xaml\generate.ps1:83 char:14
+     if (-not TryGet-Assembly $name $assemblyObject)
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Missing closing ')' after expression in 'if' statement.
At C:\Users\James\Code\csharp\Shims.Xaml\generate.ps1:80 char:1
+ {
+ ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At C:\Users\James\Code\csharp\Shims.Xaml\generate.ps1:83 char:51
+     if (-not TryGet-Assembly $name $assemblyObject)
+                                                   ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At C:\Users\James\Code\csharp\Shims.Xaml\generate.ps1:91 char:1
+ }
+ ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator
```

Why does this happen, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Why don’t you show us your `TryGetAssembly` as you wrote it in C#?

Comment: That being said, for your syntax errors, you need to add parentheses around the operand of `-not`.

Comment: @poke Awesome, thank you! That solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since function calls are usually without parentheses in PowerShell, this has the unfortunate effect that operator precendences don’t appear as useful as in other languages.

In particular the `-not` (or `!`) operator generally requires that you wrap its operand completely inside parentheses:

```
if (-not (TryGet-Assembly $name $assemblyObject))
```

Or with the alternate alias `!` for `-not`:

```
if (!(TryGet-Assembly $name $assemblyObject))
```

I personally prefer the explicit `-not` though as it is more visible between those parentheses.